# Super Table -> Matrix data loss

Tags: plugin-supertable

I updated to the newest Craft Version 3.1.1. Since then I have the following problem. I lost all the data from Matrix Filed stored in a Super Table Field after changing Field Setup (Matrix - Asset props.) again.

Setting:
Craft CMS: 3.1.1, 
Super Table: 2.0.14

1)
I created a Super Table Field which stores a simple Text Field and a Matrix-Field with one Block which stores a simple Text and an Asset.

2)
I added the Field to a Single Entry.

3)
I created all Content with the Super Table Field in the Entry

4)
jumped back to Super Table Field Settings and changed something in the Matrix Asset properties

5) after Saving i lost all the Data in the Matrix Field, which i stored in the entry

Really bad, because the Super Table field i created in the entry was complex.

Does anyone else have the same problem? - What did I Wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, my apologies for your issues, and its a direct result of the changes made in Craft 3.1.x. Fortunately, the Craft team has been amazingly helpful in coming up with a solution.

This issue should be fixed in [Super Table 2.1.1](https://github.com/verbb/super-table/releases/tag/2.1.1) and [Craft 3.1.2](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/releases/tag/3.1.2). Please update both Super Table and Craft as these changes effect both packages.

Comment: Thx for answer! Thx for your perfect support!

Comment: I have this issue even after this update :(

Comment: This has happened to me recently